# Limit data set in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display only the first 5 records on load. This is the angular service that is generating the data set. How can I do that?

```
 myApp.service('allCurrentSettingsService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
        var allSettings = null;
        this.getList = function () {
            var def = $q.defer()
            if (allSettings) {
                def.resolve(allSettings);
            } else {
                $http.post('GetAllCurrentSettings')
                  .then(function (response) {
                      var response = $.parseJSON(response.data)
                      allSettings = response;
                      def.resolve(allSettings);
                  });
            }
            return def.promise;
        }
    }]);
```

Comment: use `limitTo` filter.

Comment: I am using this limitation for pagination. Can I do something like:$scope.query = {
        order: 'name',
        limit: 5,
        page: 1
    };

Comment: you can achieve this by using `$index` or passing 5 records based on indexing, like when you click on page 2, you have to display records between index of 5 to 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a scope variable

```
$scope.limit = 5;
```

Then, use LimitTo filter in HTML file for initial loading like

```
ng-repeat="data in query | limitTo:limit"
```

After that, if you want to load more records on the click of some button or scroll till last of the page, you can write the below code on appropriate event

```
$scope.increseLimit = function()
{
  $scope.limit+=5;
}
```

Comment: Use the Begin parameter to show last five records in LimitTo:begin

Comment: Thank you. How can I use it with : <md-table-pagination md-limit="query.limit" md-limit-options="[5, 10, 15]" md-page="query.page" md-total="{{allSettings.count}}" md-on-paginate="allSettings" md-page-select></md-table-pagination>

Comment: No you cannot use this technique with <md-table-pagination> directive. Either use that directive by looking into their documentation or simply implement your own pagination using above technique.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add  `$scope.Records = 5;`

In you html file while getting records in `ng-repeat` add `limitTo:Records`
it will simply give you last five records.

Comment: Its display first 5 records, not last 5 records.